# Show action result in ASP.NET MVC 2 application redirected page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

ASP .NET MVC2 application controller performs some action and redirects to grid page after that. Grid page can also invoked from menu. In this case no message should appear.

How to show action result ?

Is it best way to add some control to grid page which gets result message from session or query string and shows it or other idea ?

I found control in

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/309920/Displaying-action-results-to-the-user-in-ASP-NET

but it seems to be webforms specific.

How to show action result in ASP .NET MVC2 C# application ? jQuery UI is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you may use additional action parameter determines whether display message or not. Or temporary cookie. Or different request method (POST instead of GET). Or additional header.

Comment: Than you. Probably using Session["Message"] and clearing it after diaplaying or using TempData dictionary from Wiktor Zychla answer can solve this. I'm using jQuery UI. Where to find sample code form ASP.NET 3.5 MVC2 which shows closeable popup from calling action ?

Comment: I think all you need is two additional ifs: - first in script part and second in HTML part that renders div for popup content. @if(TempData.MyPopup != null) { $(function() { $('#popupDiv').popup(); }} and second @if(TempData.MyPopup != null) { <div id='popupDiv'>Message</div> }

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there exists the `TempData` dictionary, used to pass the data between two consecutive requests.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx

Take a look if it meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you. TempData dictionary is interesting. Probably same result can achieved by using Session["Message"] object and clearing it after showing message as shown in question link. I'm using jquery UI. How to force jquery UI to show this message with close icon, like orange stackoverflow messages in top or in borwsers ? Where to find sample code for this?